# optical flow using opencv in real time

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I am using Pyramid Lukas Kanade function of OpenCV to estimate the optical flow. i call the  cvCalcOpticalFlowPyrLK(const CvArr* prev, const CvArr* curr, CvArr* prev_pyr, CvArr* curr_pyr, const CvPoint2D32f* prev_features, CvPoint2D32f* curr_features, int count, CvSize win_size, int level, char* status, float* track_error, CvTermCriteria criteria, int flags):

i have a problem in getting the features coordinate. i have a set of 8 coordinates in my CvPoint2D32f* prev_features data and i have to display the future features points on my capturing image. my work is in real time, so i have to detect and display the points continues.. hope u can give me some suggestion which i have to consider in this section. thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say what's wrong with your code, because I don't see it. Anyway, did you look in default sample? I mean [lkdemo.cpp](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/lkdemo.cpp?rev=4240). It obviously should help you.